# Re sizing VirtualBox vhd with windows 7 host and windows xp client

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox

I am stuck on one step of resizing a virtual hardisk... I followed the instruction used found in this Youtube video...

[Video I followed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqK3cDLiMJU)

Well that worked.  But my windows xp virtual still had the same amount of memory.  I figured I must have missed a step somewhere...  Well, I did... you are going to want to combine partitions right?  Well, I don't have any extra partition (My original hard disk size was 10gb...   Observe...

[image: computer Management]

As you can see, I can't find any partitions to attempt to expand into?
Here is what virtual Box manager says about my hard disk...

[image: Virtual Hard drive size]

What am I missing here?